# Приложение на Rfid Считыватель С4050-Q4 не работает, а LogCat выдает E/AudioPolicyManager: unknown stream type 13

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

Возникла проблема с RFID считывателей (конкретно CHAINWAY C4050-Q4) под Android studio. Суть - у них есть Sdk, в котором есть демки. У некоторых демок, есть собранные в apk проги, которые работают. Пишу, максимально простое приложение, чтобы просто попробовать функционал:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    try {
        mReader = RFIDWithUHF.getInstance();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        showAlert(ex.getMessage());

    }

}

protected void onClick(View v)
{
    mReader.init();

    String[] res = null;

    res = mReader.readTagFromBuffer();
    if (res != null) {

        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            s += res[i] + " ";

        }
        showAlert(s);

    }
    mReader.free();

}
```

И приложение запускается, но ничего не делает. Критических вылетов нет, и LogCat просто переполняется (без фильтра) этим:

```
04-29 19:50:59.400 282-2436/? E/AudioPolicyManager: unknown stream type 13
```

В добавок Run мне дописывает это:

```
W/linker: libDeviceAPI.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0xe2e4
    libDeviceAPI.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x1
```

Jar подключены, как и so.

Если пробывать в демках их классы, то как их не вызываешь-ноль реакции (UHFReadTagFragment)(через new, даже ничего не меня в классе, просто привязывая к  моей кнопке их скан)
Тех поддержка не отвечает... SOS!

Comment: раньше вообще выскакивало такое: E/DeviceAPI_RFIDWithUHF: init() err UHFInit result:-1 . Но Я тупо перебилдил проект и вроде исчезло

Comment: Понимаю, что Вы возбуждены, но Вы быстрее получите ответ, если уберете эмоции из вопросы вместе с лишними словами, и конкретизируете свою проблему. Пока лишь можно понять лишь то, что Вы встретили трудности.

Comment: А какие конкретно лишние слова запутывают вас? Я не совсем понимаю вас

Comment: Я взял на себя смелость слегка отредактировать ответ, мне кажется что мой вариант понятнее. Я не знаю, видите ли Вы его сейчас, если нет - то Вы увидите изменения после того как правки пройдут проверку.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Уже прошли, принял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что Я совсем не внимательно читал код в демке: 
    readTagFromBuffer();

Считывает RFID метки с буфера устрйоства, но без старта буфер пуст. А для того чтобы начать сканить RFID метки нужно использовать команду :

```
mReader.startInventoryTag(0,0); // без фильтров
```

и в момент сканирования получать данные через второй поток :

```
// Класс для сканирования, работает в отдельном потоке
  static   class Working extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            String strTid;
            String strResult;
            String[] res = null;
            while (SecondProcess) {


                res = mReader.readTagFromBuffer();
                if (res != null) {
                    strTid = res[0];
                    if (strTid.length() != 0 && !strTid.equals("0000000" +
                            "000000000") && !strTid.equals("000000000000000000000000")) {
                        strResult = "TID:" + strTid + "\n";
                    } else {
                        strResult = "";
                    }
                    Log.i("data","EPC:"+res[1]+"|"+strResult);
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.obj = strResult + "EPC:" + mReader.convertUiiToEPC(res[1]) + "@" + res[2];
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }

            return(null);
        }
```

Переопределять handler для отправки данных:

```
    handler=new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            super.handleMessage(msg);
            String Message = msg.obj.toString();
            String MessageParsing[] = Message.split("@");
            AddDataScan(MessageParsing[0],MessageParsing[1]);
        }
    };
```

После сканирования надо вырубить скан:

```
mReader.stopInventory();
```

Для быстрого скана есть такая функция:

```
inventorySingleTag();
```

Притом E/AudioPolicyManager: unknown stream type 13 не относиться к программе никаким боком.

Comment: mReader.init(); и mReader.free(); использовать тоже